# org reveal: remember page after refreshing in browser

Tags: html, emacs, org-mode, reveal.js

I am new to org-reveal, in the process of making a longish presentation. Whenever I add contents or edit the code of an existing slide in emacs, I html-export, then refresh my web browser to see the results.

The presentation always returns to slide #1 in the browser. How can I make the browser (Firefox) remember the slide I was previously on? Is there a reveal option for that, or is it Firefox-specific.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Use menu entry ” C-c C-e R S” to export only current subtree, without
>   the title slide and the table of content, for a quick preview of your
>   current edition.

Once you do that, going to your browser and refreshing your presentation should update the contents without taking you back to slide #1.

Comment: Thanks @DanielG ! (and sorry for the late reply, kids on Easter holidays ate my time). Could you pls point to the documentation? C-c C-e R offers no S option in my installation (only options R or B). Probably need to configure that in my .emacs file, but I've been unable to locate more documentation than [this](https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal).

Comment: Hi @emagar, that's exactly the documentation I meant. Before TIPS, in the end of the file, you'll find the quote I posted. Did you check that your ox-reveal.el is up to date?

Comment: Well @DanielG, updating org and ox-reveal did the trick of adding the missing S option. But now exporting returns an error. I'll continue my research...

Comment: OK, problem solved. As it turns out, you need to start from a 'fresh' emacs session when updating 'org' [as mentioned here](http://tonyballantyne.com/tech/elpa-org-mode-and-invalid-function-org-with-silent-modifications/). Now org-reveal works well and has the S option to export. Thanks @DanielG !